# Why my go benchmark is used a lot memory after some breaking point

Tags: go, benchmarking

I run this benchmark on my Macbook Pro M1 with golang `1.16.5`.
It is quite interesting that if the loop times increase to 10 times, the execution time and memory usage go crazy.

my instruction `$ go test -v -bench=. -run=none . -benchmem -cpuprofile=cpu.out`

```golang
func BenchmarkFakeRead(b *testing.B) {
    FakeRead(1)
}

func BenchmarkFakeRead10x(b *testing.B) {
    FakeRead(10)
}

func FakeRead(times int){
    for i:=0; i< times; i++ {
        rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    }
}
```

Here is result

```
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: mutex-benchmark
BenchmarkFakeRead
BenchmarkFakeRead-8             1000000000               0.1371 ns/op          0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFakeRead10x
BenchmarkFakeRead10x-8                 1        1271714125 ns/op        29036312 B/op      75749 allocs/op
```

The result is quite strange, especially the memory usage.
Do I do anything wrong here?

---

Thanks for @Zyl pointed out that the cryto could have some underline buffer.
But I change the FakeRead to simply add up loop, the situation is the same.

```golang
func BenchmarkFakeRead(b *testing.B) {
    FakeRead(1e9)
}

func BenchmarkFakeRead10x(b *testing.B) {
    FakeRead(5e9)
}

func FakeRead(times int){
    for i:=0; i< times; i++ {}
}
```

```golang
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: mutex-benchmark
BenchmarkFakeRead
BenchmarkFakeRead-8             1000000000               0.3178 ns/op          0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFakeRead10x
BenchmarkFakeRead10x-8                 1        1600087667 ns/op             288 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
```

Comment: Your loop should run from `i := 0; i < b.N; i++`, not a fixed number. A fixed number is likely to confuse the benchmark framework.

Comment: Oh! Good points. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Here is my hot take on this: any cryptographically secure random number generation requires a source of randomness of extremely high quality, which can supply random data only at a limited rate. What I guess you are seeing is the OS or standard library having some buffered randomness available, but being temporarily starved when requesting much at once.

Comment: @Zyl Thanks for pointing out the underline buffer issue. I change the test function to simply adding number loop, the situation is the same.

Comment: @Zyl: there are decently fast CSPRNG algorithms that are secure enough for some uses.  But in this case, for generating an RSA *key*, yeah you'd expect an implementation to try to get some true randomness, not just a secure PRNG.  OTOH, some other parts of RSA key generation involve probabilistic primality testing and are pretty slow themselves.  Most modern CPUs have a hardware RNG that can be read pretty efficiently; I'd assume M1 does, but I don't know how Go on MacOS uses it.  So I don't think it's likely that generating RSA keys would exhaust `/dev/random` or a HW buffer.